# Possible to replicate jQuery's separation of JS events from inline attributes in ASP.NET AJAX?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

Can something like this, borrowed from jQuery, be done without jQuery and with `ASP.NET AJAX` only?

```
<a href="nojslink.html" class="clickMe">Click Me</a>
```

And then in an external JS file:

```
$('a.clickMe').click(function(){  
   alert('Thanks for clicking');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
$addHandler($get(elementName),'eventname',function handler());
```

So, closer to the example:

```
$addHandler($get(elementName),'click',function() {alert('Thanks for clicking')});
```

As far as I know, `ASP.NET Ajax` doesn't support CSS selectors like jquery, so you would have to do that yourself.